# Solving quadratics using $y=a(x-p)^2+q$ ?

Tags: quadratics

The vertex is $(-4, 2)$ and the y-int is $(-3,-1)$.  How would I solve this, or find out what "$a$" is so I can write the equation and graph it?

Comment: The y intercept should lie on the $y$ axis. $(-3,-1)$ doesn't, so it isn't the $y$ intercept.

Answer (score 1):

You have the equation
$$
y = a(x-p)^2 + q
$$
Note that the vertex for this quadratic is at $(p, q)$, so we know that $p = -4$ and $q = 2$.  This gives us:
$$
y = a(x+4)^2 + 2
$$
Now, plugging in our point $(-3, -1)$, we get:
$$
-1 = a(-3+4)^2 + 2 \Rightarrow a = -3
$$
Therefore our equation is:
$$
y = -3(x+4)^2 + 2
$$

Comment: Thanks for the help, the p and q is something i do understand. 


the question that i have to answer is "Set the quadratic function of the graph going through the point (-3, -1) 
and a peak / valley is at (-4,2)."


the vertex is (-4,2) then right? and the y-intercept (-3,-1).
When i do do the math answer like you gave me it says not good. Sorry for my english maybe i didn't asked my question right.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. Maybe the y intercept is supposed to be $(-3, 0)$?

Comment: y-intercepts are of the form (0,a). x-intercepts are of the form (a,0).

Comment: Woops, random typo there: I meant $(0, -1)$.

Answer (score 0):

The [vertex form](http://www.mathwarehouse.com/geometry/parabola/standard-to-vertex-form.php) of a parabola tells you that $(p,q)$ is the vertex of the parabola (so $p=-4, q=2$). Now, plug in the other point, and solve for $a$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, the p and q is something i do understand. the question that i have to answer is "Set the quadratic function of the graph going through the point (-3, -1) and a peak / valley is at (-4,2)." the vertex is (-4,2) then right? and the y-intercept (-3,-1). When i do do the math answer like you gave me it says not good. Sorry for my english maybe i didn't asked my question right.